# Cannot do any queries on BLOB and CLOB columns (DB2/PHP/Laravel/Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, db2

I am currently working on a simple CRUD application for work and have come across an issue with BLOBs and CLOBs. I am unable to do any queries with any column of this type. I am not allowed to drop, or alter these either. The error I get is SQL error:

> [IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0005W Option value changed

. From my understanding I get this error because the driver doesn't understand what a blob is.

I've tried casting this to varchar and it works without eloquent, but my company wants this done using eloquent (as I already have a CRUD API working fine with MySQL, but it does not contain BLOB or CLOB).

This approach works perfectly fine :

```php
$conn = odbc_connect('example','username','password');
        $query = "SELECT cast(BLOB_COLUMN as varchar(32000)) FROM TABLE fetch first 1 row only";
        $stmt = odbc_prepare($conn , $query);
        odbc_execute($stmt);

        while($driver = odbc_fetch_array($stmt)){

            $drivers[] = $driver;

        }
            return $drivers;
    }
```

But I cannot Implement something like this with eloquent. I have tried casting like so:
Model

```php
protected $casts = [
        'BLOB_COLUMN' => 'string',
        'CLOB_COLUMN' => 'string',
    ];
```

Controller (allRecords)

```php
public function allRecords() {
        $data = Model::all();

        return $data;
    }
```

Route:

```php
Route::get('model', 'ModelController@allRecords');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Side note: I hope I have explained this with a good amount of detail as I have only been programming for a little under a year in college and started PHP/Laravel less than a month ago.

Comment: The ibm_db2 driver does indeed understand what a LOB is, it has a [special method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.db2-lob-read.php) for reading LOB data, but it looks like your ORM framework is not equipped to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your sql query in laravel simply

```
Model::select(DB::raw('cast(BLOB_COLUMN as varchar(32000))'))
       ->first();
```

Comment: It seems to be returning false values instead of an error I could work with.
New function:
```php
public function allRecords() {
     $data = Model::select(DB::raw('CAST(BLOBCOLUMN AS varchar(32000)) + CAST(CLOBCOLUMN AS varchar(32000))'))->get();
     return $data;
    }
```
New output:
```php
[{"1":null},{"1":null},{"1":null}]
```

Comment: Scratch that, it seems to work as intended! I just wasn't  understanding correctly at first glance. Thanks a lot ! Now time to work this in :)